# How to update UIView.intrinsicContentSize when depending on a subview being moved in an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a header view which contains a label and a background image. In its "expanded" state, the label is below the background image. The grey space represents the `intrinsicContentSize`, which extends from the top of the background to the bottom of the label:

[image]

When it animates, the background image shrinks, and the label moves up to overlap the image. The height of `intrinsicContentSize` will match the bottom of the label's frame until it crosses over the background image, at which point it will match the height of the background image:

[image]

I'm using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to change the frames of both views in a way that is interactive and cancelable. The animation is simple, but I cannot figure out how to update `intrinsicContentSize` while the animation is running. There doesn't seem to be a way to observe the `UIViewPropertyAnimator.fractionComplete` property.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without seeing your animation code. Usually you'd use `intrinsicContentSize` with AutoLayout, not frame setting. You could try using `sizeToFit` or `sizeThatFits` instead, and additionally call `layoutIfNeeded` within the animation block. If you have a good reason to stick with `intrinsicContentSize` then you may need to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` during your animation.